# Support for OpenJDK and Upgrade to CDH 6

Tags: cloudera-cdh

We currently have CDH 5.15.0 running in our environments and have a necessity to support OpenJDK. Does upgrading to CDH 6  help in supporting OpenJDK? If yes, can we directly upgrade from CDH 5.15.0 to CDH 6 or do we have to downgrade first to CDH 5.14 and then upgrade to CDH 6 ( documentation does not show direct upgrade from CDH 5.15 to CDH 6 https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_install_upgrade_notes.ht...).

Thank you for your time in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following reply for the issue helpful,

Based on the latest documentation:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/release-notes/topics/rg_java_requirements.html

> OpenJDK 8 is supported in Cloudera Enterprise 6.1.0 and higher, as well as Cloudera Enterprise 5.16.1 and higher.

Also upgrade from Cloudera Enterprise 5.15 to 6.1 is supported. Based on our current version, we can use below two doc links to start with:
- For Cloudera Manager:
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/upgrade/topics/ug_cm_upgrade_before.html#cm_upgrad...
- For CDH: 
https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/upgrade/topics/ug_cdh_upgrade_before.html#ug_cdh_u...